# Print client-side PrinterJob

Tags: jsf, primefaces, printing, jsf-2.2

I have a hard time and I'm not finding a viable solution. It is a project in JSF with the web server.

I'm trying to print  on a Bematech 4200 printer, I'm using this code to list printers  but the code returns the server printers.

```
PrintService services[] = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
```

I really need printers from client-side, the machine with printer and drivers already installed with my app open on browser .

I  can not convert the Graphics2D to image, so that it displays the img by the browser.

I did a text on page and print it, but it doesn't use all available espaces

I thought in convert Graphics2D to a PDF image, and print the PDF but probably it will not use all the paper.

How can I list all printers from machine with system open? (client-side without ask which one, it will be parameterized)

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done from the server. The only option you have that I know (knew) of to actually directly print on the client is using a signed applet

Comment: Exactly, otherwise he can send a pdf to browser and then user can print it from there.

Comment: Yep, that is always possible

Comment: I have been there and went for printing from PDF as we cannot force users to install jre to run applets.

Comment: Question is little old, I have same concern, Can we print JSF-Java Streams [Graphics2D] using JavaScript ?

Comment: @Sarz: new questions in new questions please